# "In which time" is correct as well as "in what time"?

Tags: style

I have to ask my friend "**In** **what time** the class it will start tomorrow". My question is if the using of "**In which time** the class will start tomorrow" is correct as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct usage is "**At** what time will the class start tomorrow?"

You could also say "When does the class start tomorrow?" That is more colloquial. "**At** **what** time..." is more correct but a little formal. You can also say "**At what hour**..." but that is rather old-fashioned now.

"**In** what time" is used to query duration. For example: "**In** what time can you run a mile?", i.e. "How long does it take you to run a mile?"